# how to handle app close unexpectedly in flutter

Tags: flutter, location, google-maps-flutter

I have flutter apps that contain location package and google-maps-flutter package inside my screen.. but whenever I install my app in debug version... my app always close unexpectedly... is there a reason why my app that contain google maps and location package always get sudden close or get lost connection to device and is there a way to prevent that problem?

Comment: if you are getting an error in the console please share it

Comment: I didn't get any error in console.. I always get message ```lost connection to device``` in my console and my app is closed.. it is also happen when I install in debug version

Comment: what device are you using ? Android or ios?

Comment: this is most likely because the application is throwing an exception in the first page itself. for debugging purpose could you try moving it to another page and try to debug when you open the new page.

Comment: @subham I am using android and I keep getting sudden close in my apps

Comment: @AnirudhBagri my first page is fine and when I move to second page that contain real time location  (I am using location package and google-maps-flutter package)... I get message ```lost connection to device``` after 3-5 seconds waiting for update location user... usually I will get an ```paused on exception``` when there is something wrong.. but here I can not figure out whats the problem that makes sudden closed app

Comment: Do you map license file in place? Also, Make sure you ask for location permission before enabling the map.

Comment: @AnirudhBagri I have added permission for location by doing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61764390/how-to-handle-gps-location-provider-requires-access-fine-location-permission/61765112#61765112... but would you like to give me idea about what do you mean by map license file in place

Comment: To use Google Maps, you must have API key in place.

Comment: @AnirudhBagri I have added my apikey in androidmanifest

Comment: is there something that I should add like build.gradle or something?

Comment: did you try to launch the application from Android Studio to get the phone's console to know the reason of the crash ?

Comment: And you have playservices.json file also added?

Comment: @AnirudhBagri yes I have added it... is there a relation between apikey inside android manifest file and apikey inside google-service.json?

Comment: because when I take a look... apikey inside my android manifest is different with apikey inside google-service.json

Comment: you need to add both of them.

Comment: I open new question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61788319/how-to-handling-app-that-get-sudden-close-in-flutter and update the error message.. maybe anyone can help me